# Synergy can't connect with new router

Tags: windows-10, router, ubuntu-18.04, synergy

I have been using Synergy (from Symless) for 1.5 years now. I moved to a new place (so new router; a ZTE ZXHN F618 - ZTE PON ONT) and I cant make it work.
I read that this router's WLAN and LAN is on different subnets. How can I check that this is true? Can this be the cause ?

I changed literally nothing from the working setup, only the server ip on the client. I have the same version as well.

On the server I have 2 IP addresses: `192.168.1.8`, `192.168.181.193`.

On the client, when I try to connect I get the following error messages:

- For the `192.168.1.8` IP: "No route to host"
- For the `192.168.181.193`IP: "Timed out"

I tried:

- Changing the port to 8081 (as [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1060407/1269142) suggests).
- I also tried to open ports in the firewall, still nothing, I cant even ping between the devices.
- The netmasks are the same (`255.255.255.0`)
- Tried with both firewalls off as well.

Comment: what is the client's IP?

Comment: 192.168.1.9, and the default route is 192.168.1.1 if that matters.

Comment: What is the make and model of the new router? Wonder if UPnP is an issue?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 ZTE GPON ONT ZXHN F618 (and also thanks for the edit)

Comment: for testing purposes you should disable the firewall on both clients and test ping (must work) and see if synergy will work then. UPnP should not be an issue as your are inside the same subnet (GW, Win, Ubuntu)

Comment: @Zina as you can see in the question, I tried with both firewalls off. I also figured out that the router handles the WLAN and LAN in different subnets. How can I 1.) configure synergy to work on different subnets? or 2.) Configure the router to handle wlan and lan on the same subnet? OR is there any other method that I am not aware of and can make this work?

Comment: I saw that you turned off the firewalls, I was just stating that a ping then really should work. Why do you have on client with two IPs? You really need a wired and WLAN connection on diff subnets? If not, you should reconfigure your route either to same subnets on LAN and WLAN (can't give you recommendations without knowing more how/why the config is set like this - check the router manual) or you should see if the router is able to route the LAN to WLAN and vice versa. if you would maybe add your `ipconfig /all` and `ifconfig` or `ip addr` from both clients to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I managed to figure it out. It was a problem with my setup, not with synergy.
The router provided by the ISP (ZTE GPON ONT ZXHN F618) handles LAN and WLAN on different subnets, so I had to call them to set it to bridge mode (because I dont had access to modify it from the admin console), and after that I connected a secondary router (LAN1-> WAN) and configured the PPPoE connection on it. Now this secondary router connects to my PC via lan and to my laptop wirelessly, so they are now on the same subnet and synergy works.